# How can I detect that emacs-server is running from a shell prompt?

Tags: shell, bash

I want to have my .bashrc detect if running emacsclient would work in lieu of running emacs.  Basically:

```
if emacs_server_is_running; then
    EDITOR=emacsclient
    VISUAL=emacsclient
else
    EDITOR=emacs
    VISUAL=emacs
fi
```

What would I put in the `emacs_server_is_running` function to accomplish this aim?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're making this too hard.  From the the `emacsclient(1)` man page:

> -a, --alternate-editor=EDITOR
>
> if the Emacs server is not running, run the specified editor instead.  This can also be specified via the `ALTERNATE_EDITOR' environment variable.
>
> If the value of EDITOR is the empty string, then Emacs is started in daemon mode and emacsclient will try to connect to it.

Comment: If that was ever true, it's not anymore.

Comment: First, it was true or I wouldn't have mentioned it.

Second, it still is. With `emacsclient --version` 25.3, the help text says: "-a EDITOR, --alternate-editor=EDITOR Editor to fallback to if the server is not running. If EDITOR is the empty string, start Emacs in daemon mode and try connecting again."

Answer (score 12):

From a shell script, you could do something like this:

```
emacsclient -ca false -e '(delete-frame)'
```

This will open a new emacs window then quickly close it, returning true on success. If no emacs server exists, the alternate editor is /bin/false, which returns false.

Answer (score 8):

@madumlao came up with a great idea in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10565139).  We may do slightly better, however:

```
emacsclient -a false -e 't'
```

This doesn't require opening a new frame and works in a case when:

```
sh-4.4$ emacsclient -a false -e '(delete-frame)'
*ERROR*: Terminal type "dumb" is not powerful enough to run Emacs
```

Answer (score 6):

I read the answers, but none of this did fit my use case, where I did not want to start an server if not running and also wanted to avoid blocking forever.

Looking at the `server-force-stop` function in emacs, it simply deletes the server file in either `server-auth-dir` or `server-socket-dir` which in my case are `/tmp/emacs1000/server` or `~/.emacs.d/server`.

Knowing this, to test if a server is running we can simply do:

`test -e "/tmp/emacs1000/server" || test -e "~/.emacs.d/server"`

Comment: Exactly the thing I was looking for!

Comment: This works, but relies (probably safely) on those variables (`server-auth-dir` or `server-socket-dir`) not having been changed from their defaults. [ocodo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28561282/915044) (below) is IMHO better, since it will find the open sockets regardless of values set by the user.

Comment: Debian sid 2023.09.21: Could not find any file named 'server' for emacs.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
emacs_server_is_running(){
    lsof -c emacs | grep server | tr -s " " | cut -d' ' -f8
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a couple of ways, neither of them foolproof:

```
function emacs_server_is_running()
{
    ps -ef | grep emacsserver | grep -v grep > /dev/null
}

function emacs_server_is_running()
{
    netstat -a | grep esrv > /dev/null
}
```

---

Or instead of setting this up when the shell starts (after all, the server could die or the server could start after you have logged in), why not make the check at the time you need to edit something:

```
EDITOR=$HOME/emacs_try_client_first
VISUAL=$HOME/emacs_try_client_first
```

where `$HOME/emacs_try_client_first` could be as simple as

```
#!/bin/sh
# emacs_try_client_first
emacsclient $@ || emacs $@
```

Comment: You don't have to do `grep -v grep` - you can make your first one look like this: `grep [e]macsserver` this is often done when grepping the output of `ps`.

Comment: @DW You know? Everybody always complains about that `| grep -v grep` idiom, but now finally someone's done something about it!

Comment: Debian sid 2023.09.19: No process named emacsserver. No network connection eserv.

Answer (score 3):

I find it convenient to redefine the `emacs` command by adding the following to `~/bin/emacs` (which must be in your path):

```
#!/bin/sh
# if emacsclient can't connect to the daemon, try to launch it first
emacsclient -c "$@" || (/usr/bin/emacs --daemon; emacsclient -c "$@")
```

After this is in place, one can simply type `emacs` to start emacs, and a server will be automatically started if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. When I launch emacs, it checks if there is already a server. If this is the first instance of emacs, it starts in server mode.
Then, when I view/edit a file, I want to connect to the server. This way the file is opened very quickly since no new emacs instance is started. Reusing the results of @mob above, I came up with the following working solution:

**(1) .emacs**

I have the following snippet in my `.emacs` file:

```
;; start emacs-server if not running
    (add-hook 'after-init-hook
        (lambda ()
          (require 'server)
          (unless (server-running-p)
            (server-start))))
```

If this is the first emacs instance, it starts in server mode.

**(2) .bashrc**

```
#########################
# START: Emacs settings #
#########################
export EDITOR=/home/jabba/Dropbox/home/jabba/bin/emacs_try_client_first
export VIEWER=$EDITOR

alias vi=$EDITOR
alias e=vi  # i.e., $EDITOR
alias em=vi # same as above

export TERM="xterm-256color"
#######################
# END: Emacs settings #
#######################
```

I've used vim for 15+ years, so when I want to edit a file, I write automatically `vi file`. Since I want to switch to emacs, I defined this alias :) The commands "vim" and "emacs" start a new instance. Using the aliases "vi", "e", and "em" you can connect to a running emacs instance (which is the server). If there is no running emacs server, a new instance will be opened (in server mode).

**(3) emacs_try_client_first**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function emacs_server_is_running()
{
    ps ux | grep "\bemacs\b" | grep -v grep >/dev/null
}

if emacs_server_is_running; then
    emacsclient -n "$@" 2>/dev/null &
else
    emacs "$@" 2>/dev/null &
fi
```

It also works nicely with Midnight Commander, where F3 is view, F4 is edit. In MC, if you want to use emacs, go to Configuration and switch off the internal view and internal edit.

**Edit:** the `after` macro was added. Edit #2: it was not necessary after all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my setup

```
#!/bin/sh
emacsclient -s IRC -c $* || (emacs --daemon=IRC && emacsclient -s IRC -c --eval "rcirc" $*)
```

It connects to the IRC server and opens a frame; if the server if off, it starts it, runs the elisp code and then tries again.

Answer (score 0):

my solution is based in the first solution exposed by Jabba, but using `emacs --script`, this is useful for me to have the emacs server status (running or not running) within a bash script. I use this for multiple emacs servers, that is why I have a variable for the server name

```
server_ts="servername"

tmp_file=`mktemp --tmpdir=/tmp emacs-manager.XXXXXX`

echo ";;
(require 'server)
(progn (setq server-name \"$server_ts\")           
   (if     (server-running-p)
           (princ \"1\")
           (princ \"0\")))
" > $tmp_file
isrunning=$(emacs --script $tmp_file 2>/dev/null)
rm $tmp_file
echo "is running: $isrunning"
```

before doing this I tried looking for the socket files, and parsing the output of the `ps` command. The former fails sometimes when the computer crashes, the socket files still there but there is no emacs process. The latter is not easy since emacs server could be started in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 0):

1. In emacs check the value of `server-socket-dir`.
2. Check if there are some files in this directory. If does, then the server is running.

Here an example I use to get org-pomodoro timer to my xfce panel:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$(ls -A /run/user/1000/emacs/)" ]; then
   echo "Emacs server is down"
else
   emacsclient --eval '(pomodoro-string-for-menu-bar)'| sed 's/["()]//g'
fi
```